# IBMSBT XPages custom endpoint Callback_uri vs redirect_uri

Tags: oauth-2.0, xpages, xpages-extlib, ibm-sbt

I'm trying to use the sbt in xpages with a custom endpoint i.e a new one defined in faces config using the class com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.OAuth2Endpoint

The authorisation url it generates is in the format of 
&client_id=xx&callback_uri=xxx

however the api i'm trying to use expects a parameter of redirect_uri

Looking at the spec for OAuth2 it appears that the convention is to use redirect_uri rather than callback_uri.

Is there a different end point class I can use which would use redirect_uri instead for the auth handler?
NB: I've searched the source code and "OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI" isn't used anywhere so I guess not, which makes me think I've misunderstood how to use it

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue for our Basecamp demo application for IBM Connect 2014.

I have inherited a new [endpoint](https://github.com/sbasegmez/ic14demos/blob/master/demo1-XPages/odp-ic14xpages/Code/Java/com/developi/ic14/extensions/BaseCampEndpoint.java) and [handler](https://github.com/sbasegmez/ic14demos/blob/master/demo1-XPages/odp-ic14xpages/Code/Java/com/developi/ic14/extensions/BaseCampOAuth2Handler.java) for this purpose.

In the handler class I had to rewrite `getAuthorizationNetworkUrl()` and `getAccessTokenForAuthorizedUser()` methods to change those url parameters.

Overriding these methods might not be safe for the future of course. Instead, you might get the original URL and do some string operations to change desired parameters.

```
@Override
public String getAuthorizationNetworkUrl() {
  String newUrl=super();
  // Do string operations
  return newUrl;
}
```

Checking if anything changed for the new version of SBT would be needed. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  Managed to get it work last night using that approach. Had to also override getAccessTokenForAuthorizedUsingPOST() in the end. That got the authentication to work but now another issue with using the <xe:restJsonData> control - a subject of another SO post!. THanks again

Comment: Shoot in another question :)

Comment: [Another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860431/xpages-sbt-xerestjsondata-java-util-arraylist-incompatible-with-com-ibm-com) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SmartCloudOAuth2Endpoint, instead of the plain oauth2 endpoint. This endpoint is a custom endpoint for SmartCloud which uses redirect_uri

https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/blob/cd373c78971bb31e1902f177eddcb33d029ae474/sdk/com.ibm.sbt.core/src/main/java/com/ibm/sbt/services/endpoints/SmartCloudOAuth2Endpoint.java

Comment: Thanks. That's a neat solution and means i don't have to override the methods myself