# Xpages SBT <xe:restJsonData> & java.util.ArrayList incompatible with com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject

Tags: json, xpages, ibm-sbt

I'm trying to use the Endpoint functionality in SBT within XPages with a different rest service (to those in the examples).
The authentication is working after a few tweaks (thanks Serdar!) but I wanted to mimic the StackOverflow example and use the response via a `<xe:restJsonData>` and repeat control.

Using the SO example as I starting point if I change the params to match my service I get this error...

`Error while reading the JSON stream
java.util.ArrayList incompatible with com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject`

I'm guessing it's something to do with the splitpath as the resulting json doesn't have a common parent as such. 
Looks a bit like this (edited)...

`[
  {
    "user_id": 1688810,
    "space_id": null,
    "type": "user",
    "title": [
      "Workflow Architect"
    ],
    "external_id": null,
    "last_seen_on": "2014-07-21 06:42:03",
    "name": "XXX XXX"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 1998697,
    "name": "YYY YYY",
    "rights": [
      "view"
    ],
    "external_id": null,
    "space_id": null,
    "title": [
      "Owner"
    ],
    "org_id": null,
    "country": "United States",
    "type": "user",
    "last_seen_on": "2014-07-20 16:52:03",
    "location": [
      "Amarillo"
    ]
  }
]`

I've tried a split path of blank or "/" but get the same error. 
I know the data is coming back as putting in a computed value of
`@Endpoint("podio").xhrGet("/contact/").getData();`
shows it ok (raw)

Any ideas how I can split this result to work  or is it fundamentally not possible with that object as the json is complex?
Thanks!

Full stack trace...

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Error while reading the JSON stream
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.sbt.generic.GenericRestJsonDataSource$JsonAccessor.loadBlock(GenericRestJsonDataSource.java:137)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.DataBlockAccessor.findBlockByIndex(DataBlockAccessor.java:344)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.DataBlockAccessor.prefetchData(DataBlockAccessor.java:292)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.DataAccessorModel.getRowCount(DataAccessorModel.java:93)
at com.ibm.xsp.model.TabularDataModel.isRowAvailable(TabularDataModel.java:96)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.DataAccessorModel.isRowAvailable(DataAccessorModel.java:69)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.isRowAvailable(UIDataIterator.java:523)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.pushVars(UIDataIterator.java:504)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.setRowIndex(UIDataIterator.java:469)
at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.IteratorRenderer.encodeRows(IteratorRenderer.java:62)
at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.IteratorRenderer.encodeChildren(IteratorRenderer.java:55)
at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.encodeChildren(UIDataIterator.java:725)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1315)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1299)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList incompatible with com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.sbt.generic.GenericRestJsonDataSource$JsonAccessor.loadBlock(GenericRestJsonDataSource.java:121)
... 43 more'
```

Comment: Can you add the full Java stack for this specific error? (from logs under workspace)

Comment: splitPath is the XPath region in case your items are splitted by seperate nodes. In your case, it should be empty.

Comment: The LoadBlock method of GenericRestJsonDataSource has this
`} catch(Exception ex) {
                throw new FacesExceptionEx(ex,"Error while reading the JSON stream");
            }`

which makes it hard to find out what the real error is. I have the source code in eclipse and want to add more logging/change exception handling etc but I don't now how to build it again and get it back into domino

Comment: Yeah, I now remember :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have bumped the same problem before. That's an incapability of `GenericRestJsonDataSource`. If the remote service provides an array, instead of an object, the data from the client service returns an `ArrayList` of `JsonJavaObject`'s.

However it expects an `JsonJavaObject` that contains an `ArrayList` of `JsonJavaObject`'s.

That's why in the previous example of BaseCamp (at the linked question) I have designed an additional Java bean that pulls the data and maintains its own List structures. That also helped me a lot on caching.

Your data should be in a format like:

```
{
  items: [
     {
       prop: value, ....
     },
     {
       prop: value, ....
     }
  ]
}
```

Just like in the SO example. In this case `splitPath` should be `items`.

That's an easy fix within the class in fact. The accessor class in the `GenericRestJsonDataSource` should be modified to check if the returning item is an `ArrayList`. However at the time, it seemed like a more convenient method to design my own Service bean.

Comment: Thanks! When you say easy fix do you mean fix and do a custom build of SBT yourself?  If so do you know of any instructions as to how?  I'd like to be able to edit it in eclipse, build, create a new update site and upload back to my dev server.  I can submit a new issue to the github project but would be nice to test changes myself

Comment: FYI I will be eventually using a similar approach to your basecamp example i.e. access via beans. The service I'm using has it's own Java API anyway but the entry point needs the client tokens so will still use SBT for the dance.
Would be nice though to get the <xe:restJsonData> to work as is a great way to get something working quickly as a demo/proof of concept before coding beans

Comment: Martin, The core libraries are easy thanks to Maven. I think building your own development environment for xsp plugins will not be different from the procedure on configuring development environment for Extension Library. You should configure your Eclipse to target OSGi on XSP. I have worked on SBT.core but not on XSP plugins. You are right about restJsonData component. It's very useful for demo.

Comment: NB: I've managed to put a fix into GenericRestJsonDataSource in my own build. Got my own fork here https://github.com/MartinRolph/SocialSDK  Works great as I can now use the <xe:restJsonData> control directly! thanks again for your help